# text for UILabel inside cell not fully displaying

Tags: ios, swift

I am attempting to display text that is fetched from somewhere to be display in my cell like so:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reviewCellID, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ReviewCell

    if let comment = selectedCompany.reviews?[indexPath.row].comment {
        cell.commentLabel.text = comment
    }

    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if let comment = selectedCompany.reviews?[indexPath.row].comment {
        let height:CGFloat = estimateFrameForText(comment).height
        return CGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.width - 12, height + 70)
    }
}

func estimateFrameForText(text: String) -> CGRect {
    let size = CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width - 36, height: 1000)
    let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading.union(.UsesLineFragmentOrigin)
    return NSString(string: text).boundingRectWithSize(size, options: options, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 12.0)!], context: nil)
}
```

The problem is that not all the text is shown. Sometimes the text inside the cell can be pretty long. Therefore, it ends up not display all the text in some of the cells once the user scrolls up and down the collectionview. See below where the text inside both cells are the exact same

[image]

I have never used a cache before but I think i need to use one here so the text is loaded inside the cell properly.  I could be wrong.

Comment: Does `comment = selectedCompany...` even compile? Shouldn't it be `if let comment = selectedCompany...`?

Comment: Yeah sorry i'll fix it

Comment: Can you draw a border around the `cell.titleLabel`? That way we will know if its frame is correct or not. To draw border: `cell.titleLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1` and then `cell.titleLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor()`

Comment: Bleh, I should of proof read my code.  Ignore `titleLabel`.  It's the gibberish below title label that I'm concerned about which is the `commentLabel`. Border added

Comment: So the frame is not correct here. Can you try to call `cell.titleLabel.sizeToFit()` right after you set its text?

Comment: Still the same problem occurs

Comment: Please check if you did set the autolayout constraints correctly. It should have leading/trailing/top constraints to the cell. It should NOT have height constraint.

Comment: I don't think you're understanding my question. Sometimes this works completely fine, where the text fits in the box perfectly and there is no problem.  But, when the user scrolls down the collection view too fast, the cells have to reload again and can't handle reloading the text all over again.  Therefore, to take a shortcut and make it easier for the cell to display the text, it only displays 1 line rather than full amount because it doesn't load the data quick enough.

Comment: How about we try this? After you set the text, set its frame height to some hard-code value: `let labelRect = cell.titleLabel.frame` then `labelRect.height = 200` then `cell.titleLabel.frame = labelRect`. If all cells now display the same height, then you can try to calculate the `titleLabel`'s height after you set the text, then set that height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. All I needed to do was change `UILabel` to `UITextView`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you implemented "prepareForReuse" in your cell to clear any previous text in your labels. If it's not old text, i would add a border to the text label layer to check if its a constraint problem.  I hope it helps.